# Get the "termination status" of a twilio call

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Is it true that the twilio status callback events don't provide the termination status explicitly in a "completed" event?

The event callback request only has the following paramter names:

- AccountSid
- ApiVersion
- CallbackSource
- CallDuration
- Called
- CalledCity
- CalledCountry
- CalledState
- CalledZip
- Caller
- CallerCity
- CallerCountry
- CallerState
- CallerZip
- CallSid
- **CallStatus=completed,**
- Direction
- Duration
- From
- FromCity
- FromCountry
- FromState
- FromZip
- SequenceNumber
- SipResponseCode
- Timestamp
- To
- ToCity
- ToCountry
- ToState
- ToZip

Is there any other way to get the termination status viz. busy, canceled, completed, failed, or no-answer?